# JavaScriptファイルからPythonのコードを実行することは可能ですか？

Tags: javascript, python

JavaScriptファイルで取得したキーワードをPythonの関数の引数に指定して実行し、
さらにその結果（関数の戻り値）をJavaScript側で受け取ることは可能ですか？

JavaScriptはブラウザ（Firefox）上で実行しています。
Pythonもブラウザ上で実行したいです。

Comment: JavaScripとPythonはそれぞれどこで実行する想定でしょうか？

Comment: 現状、JavaScriptのコードはローカールで実行しています。
どこで実行するかによって変わってくるんでしょうか？
JavaScript, Python共に初心者なので詳しく教えていただけますか？

Comment: 例えばwindowsのプログラム、もしくはiOSやAndroidのアプリとしてさらにはWebサービスとして起動する場合はなどプログラム言語を動かすそれぞれの環境情報を記述お願いします。

Comment: JavaScriptはローカル(file:///)上で実行しています。ブラウザはFirefoxです。Pythonは3.5.2で、Macを使用しています。

Comment: @richoco 追加情報はコメントではなく質問文を編集して追記してください。

Comment: Python本家の[このページ](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming)を見るとブラウザ内で動くPythonの実装がいくつか見つかります。例えば[Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org)とか[Brython](http://brython.info/tests/console.html)。これらはPythonのコードをJavaScriptに変換してブラウザ内で実行します。

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi 教えていただき、ありがとうございます。そちらの2つについて調べてみます。

Comment: @richoco Pythonをどこで実行するかは秘密なのでしょうか？ Kenji Noguchiさんの提案はWebブラウザー上で実行することを前提としていますが、それは意図通りですか？ ともかく質問文を明確にしてください。

Comment: 「ローカル」はファイルの保存場所であり実行場所ではありません。

Answer (score 1):

#### JavaScriptは Firefoxで動かし, Pythonも 同じ Webブラウザー上で, の場合

Pythonには各種各様の実装が存在し, Webブラウザー上で動作するものもあります
ここの情報が詳しいでしょう:
(stackoverflow.com) [Python in Browser: How to choose between Brython, PyPy.js, Skulpt and Transcrypt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155551/)
(質問はもっと以前のもののようですが, その後(2019)に更新された模様)

対象の Pythonスクリプトを JavaScriptあるいは WebAssemblyへ transpileするものが多い中, まるっと一式というのもあるようです(CPythonごと)

ここに載ってなさそうな他のものに [RustPython](https://rustpython.github.io/) もあります
<del>(WebAssemblyへ transpile</del> Python自体が WASI (WebAssembly System Interface)モジュールとして動く)

---

**JavaScriptからの Python呼び出しについて (追記)**

上記 stackoverflow.comの元記事 [Running Python in the Browser](https://yasoob.me/2019/05/22/running-python-in-the-browser/) や, それぞれのドキュメントから, 大抵は JavaScriptから Python呼び出せそうですが, すべて確認できてるわけではありません

利用する場合は確認を。(その動作について)質問の場合, 条件を絞るとよいでしょう。

#### Pythonをサーバーサイドへ, Webブラウザー(JavaScript) からアクセスの場合

念の為に？ Pythonの Web フレームワークも記しときます
Web フレームワークも各種各様あります
[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python#Webアプリケーションフレームワーク](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python#Web%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF)

この他には [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/ja/) というのも

([HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP) について理解があれば) 標準パッケージにも [http.server --- HTTP サーバー](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/http.server.html) などが存在します

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptとPythonの間で相互に関数を呼ぶには、
「Eel」でしょうか？
ブラウザは、「chrome」が最適かな？
（参考URL）
http://www.inmyzakki.com/entry/2018/02/21/172202
https://qiita.com/inoory/items/f431c581332c8d500a3b
などなどを参考に自分でしこたま呆れるほど
工夫すれば不可能が可能になるかもしれません。
間違った事を書いていたらごめんなさい。